# How to setup DigitalOcean DNS link to AWS CloudFront Distribution

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, digital-ocean

I have a DNS setup with DigitalOcean for the domain

`ghazanfarmir.me`

**What I want to do?**

I would like a sub domain i.e. `static.ghazanfarmir.me` to be linked to the **CloudFront Distribution**, which then is linked to the S3 bucket containing all my assets. So I can access the CDN using the sub domain static.ghazanfarmir.me.

**What I have done so far?**

- Setup S3 bucket containing all of my assets and have created a CloudFront distribution off this S3 bucket (`d17jymztihbpvb.cloudfront.net`)

[image]

- Created CNAME record on DigitalOcean DNS for `static.ghazanfarmir.me` to the CloudFront distribution i.e. `d17jymztihbpvb.cloudfront.net`

[image]

This doesn't work, can someone please explain how this would work, or if this works at all this way?

**Update**

I am using NGINX and the problem is hitting `static.ghazanfarmir.me` loads the first site within sites-enabled directory i.e. `http://arbaeenuk.ghazanfarmir.me/`:

[image]

Comment: You need to be more specific than "this doesn't work."  What does it do?  Why do I see the following DNS lookup result? `static.ghazanfarmir.me. 300 IN CNAME ghazanfarmir.me.`  Why did you create a DNS entry at DigitalOcean DNS, when your domain's DNS is actually hosted by Cloudflare?

Comment: @Ghazanfar Mir , how did you fixed it ? Please share your answer. I need to do same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Amazon CloudFront is designed to work with their Route 53 DNS service using ALIAS resource records.

I'm not sure of the specific details of this and why the requirement. But, if you are going to use an alternate DNS name you need to make sure you configured the **Alternate Domain Name** for the cloudfront.

Beyond insuring the above is correct, you might need to move your DNS hosting to Route 53. You may be able to just delegate that particular subdomain to Route 53 depending on your DNS provider but that is beyond the scope of the question.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-cloudfront-distribution.html

Comment: I have done the Alternative Domain Name already but luck. Please see screenshots updated in the question

Comment: Moving to Route 53 is **not** necessary unless the hostname is at the apex of a DNS zone.  Otherwise, a CNAME is perfectly viable.